# Open Fire Chat Notification

Tags: push-notification, chat, openfire, whatsapp

Does openfire send chat notification when a user sends message and app is in background state ?(like in other chat apps(whats app,hike etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Mobile notifications are not supported in Openfire unless there is a plugin which provides this support (not mentioned on Openfire website under 'plugins').

Basically Openfire is an XMPP Server, and what you are looking for are Mobile Related Features like Ejabberd Business Edition (not the opensource version) by ProcessOne provides such support. However push plugin is available for Ejabberd Opensource version.